# How to Fix Mac Driver Mouse Button Emulation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, mouse, emulation

*I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1*

**Mac Drivers Mouse Emulation Not Working**

I edited /etc/sysctl.conf file with the following code:

```
# Enable mouse button emulation
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button_emulation = 1
# Set 2nd button to 87 - F11
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button2_keycode = 87
# Set 3rd button to 88 - F12
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button3_keycode = 88
```

Then I applied the changes:

```
$ sudo sysctl --system
```

***Expected result*** : xev indicates mouse press while key is pressed and mouse release, on key release.

***Actual result*** : xev does not detect mouse press while holding key down. Detects both press and release on key release.

***Control*** : emulation of button 3 works as expected.

**My Attempt To Resolve Issue:**

1. toggle between all related mouse settings. Testing the affect on each mode -- Used Gnome Tweak Tool as well.
2. rebuild kernel with a fully enabled mac emulation of mouse buttons 2 and 3.
3. compare issue with Ubuntu 16.04. Works on Ubuntu 16.04.
4. compare issue with Fedora 28. Same problem.

**Solution?**:
Since both Fedora 28 and Ubuntu 18.04 use Wayland and Gnome 3, one of those could be a problem. Another possibility is that the kernel no longer fully supports emulation, either intended or not.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue, and possibly a fix?

Comment: If this isn't specific to Ubuntu, you may have better luck on Super User.

Comment: Well it turns out that my xbindkeys file is miraculously working now. No need to go SSJ.